# Facebook Chatbot How: Programmatically get notified when call_to_action button on Facebook Page clicked or selected

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-call-to-action

Hi facebook builders :)

Do you guys know how to get notified every time users click on call_to_action buttons? Those buttons are visible at many places in facebook page for example: on page, under post, under photo on mobile devices <- this is new since about a week!...

Currently, when user click on "Send Message", they are leaded to Facebook Messenger without our webhook-backend to be notified.

It would be great if we can catch the event!
Thank you

Comment: Why should your webhook be notified, if they haven't actually messaged you yet?

Comment: @CBroe where else should I listen to, to be notified everytime the Users have just clicked on the call_to_action buttons?

Comment: Which buttons do you mean? You can only be notified about actions about your postback buttons from Messenger.

Comment: @hya That's not what I'm asking for! I want to know, when a user clicks on the call_to_action button on my Page. Not postback-button!